# How to use the DOM to set values in HTML table without using .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, dom

I recently posted some code on Code Review Stack Exchange

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8783/how-can-i-improve-performance-for-my-javascript-table-class

My code would populate an HTML table with values from an object in JavaScript

In the answer I received, it was suggested that I use the DOM to add rows to my table without using .innerHTML or jQuery.  I would like to do this, but I don't know how.

My code looks like this:

```
var html = ... // code to get html
$(tbody).html(html);
```

How can I get the rows in the variable `html` into my table body without using innerHTML or jQuery.

Comment: The "code to get HTML" is important. The point of DOM manipulation is that you don't build up a large HTML string up front, but add several smaller elements (like the rows) one by one. If you *have* to build a big HTML string up front for some other reason, there's no point in splitting it up again.

Answer (score 1):

I think the suggestion was probably that you use `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML` when placing text string contents in an element (either pre-existing, or one you're creating on the fly). It's just safer to do. The reason being: if somehow in your retrieval of the contents you get a string that has something like "`<script> //do something bad </script>`" in it, that potentially dangerous script will be executed when appended to the DOM using `.innerHTML`. However, if you use `.innerText` it will just be placed in the DOM as a string, and not be evaluated as a script to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an HTML string, your don't want to parse it yourself like Inerdial pointed it out in the comments.. Let the browser parse it for you with innerHTML/jQuery.

I will show you how to do plain DOM manipulation though:

```
var thediv = document.createElement('DIV');

thediv.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
thediv.appendChild(document.createTextNode('some text'));

document.getElementById('someElement').appendChild(thediv);
```

That's the basics, you can create tables and table rows and insert them in that fashion.

Why not use jQuery or innerHTML is another question.

EDIT: added some text to the div

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you use the approach you're trying:

```
var html = '<tr><td>This is a div</td></tr>';
$(tbody).html(html);
```

You will be using innerHTML. To avoid this, you need to create DOM nodes instead:

```
var cell = document.createElement('td');
var row = document.createElement('tr');
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

row.appendChild(cell);
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

Of course this will append an empty `td` to a `tr` and append that to the `tbody`. To place content in the cell, you'd still have to use `innerHTML`:

```
var cell = document.createElement('td');
cell.innerHTML = "This is text inside of the created 'td' DOM node.";
var row = document.createElement('tr');
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

row.appendChild(cell);
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ehShP/).

Using jQuery, this can be condensed to:

```
var cell = $('<td />').text("This is text inside of the created 'td' DOM node.");
var row = $('<tr />');
var tbody = $('tbody:first');

row.append(cell).appendTo(tbody);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ehShP/1/).

A link to a comparison of the approaches ('vanilla' JavaScript against jQuery), [at JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/jqueryvsjs).

Comment: I've written code similar to what you describe, and it mostly works, but there is one problem.  When I write `cell.setAttribute('class','evenRow')`, but application of the class to the row doesn't seem to be reflected in my document.

Comment: Use instead: `cell.className = "evenRow";` without seeing your code I can't offer insight as to why your code's not working.